# Use BeautifulSoup to get a value after a specific tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm having a very hard time getting BeautifulSoup to scrape some data for me. What's the best way to access the date (the actual numbers, 2008) from this code sample? It's my first time using Beautifulsoup, I've figured out how to scrape urls off of the page, but I can't quite narrow it down to only select the word Date, and then to only return whatever numeric date follows (in the dd brackets). Is what I'm asking even possible?

```
<div class='dl_item_container clearfix detail_date'>
    <dt>Date</dt>
    <dd>
        2008
    </dd>
</div>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried ?

Comment: I've tried using soup.find_all in various ways, also soup.select("dt"), which gets all of the labels, but I want what they're labeling in the dd brackets, but without the labels, if I soup.select("dd"), I get a tonne of values that I don't want, I only want the value specific to the label I'm looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find the `dt` tag [by text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and find the [next `dd` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
soup.find('div', class_='detail_date').find('dt', text='Date').find_next_sibling('dd').text
```

The complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class='dl_item_container clearfix detail_date'>
    <dt>Date</dt>
    <dd>
    2008
    </dd>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
date_field = soup.find('div', class_='detail_date').find('dt', text='Date')
print(date_field.find_next_sibling('dd').text.strip())
```

Prints `2008`.