# How to extract data from multiple dt and dd tags in tabled form (within a looped statement) using python v3 beautiful soup v4?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Source:**
I’ve only chosen one year for simplicity but my intention is for all years (n=117). 
https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/browse/Report/USGS%20Numbered%20Series/Open-File%20Report/
(2018 only) 
https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/browse/Report/USGS%20Numbered%20Series/Open-File%20Report/2018/

**Resources:**
I’ve found 2 blogs and 2 stack overflow forums that have steered my attempts to replicate their work but my lack of experience and the uniqueness of the website and task has proven difficult. I’ve tried next_siblings a little but to no success. Blog #1: Extract tabled data as a table:
https://journalistsresource.org/tip-sheets/research/python-scrape-website-data-criminal-justice
https://gist.github.com/phillipsm/404780e419c49a5b62a8 Blog #2: Extract data from tags into a table
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/
Stack overflow forum #1:
[Using BeautifulSoup to extract specific dl and dd list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475700/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-specific-dl-and-dd-list-elements)
Stack overflow forum #2:
[Use BeautifulSoup to get a value after a specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778394/use-beautifulsoup-to-get-a-value-after-a-specific-tag)

**Problems encountered:**
1. Each year’s publications have different “Additional Publication Details”. To help with this I can run the code I have and compiled (which is not in tabled form) the unique dt tag text headers to make sure all are captured for 2018 (pasted below). But again to do this for all years would take time…right? I'll add in a comment if necessary.
2. For statements…I find I keep having to nest “for” statements to get to final webpage where publication details live (minimum of 2 links). This seems restricting in what/how I can return data and without limiting replicating returns ([:1]), my code can very easily fail (whether it’s from the source server or what have you).
3. I have to first extract dt element text, then extract dd element text.

**Code:**
(commented out dt element grab and print statements are only for my record keeping of what’s being done. Again, I compiled unique dt element text headers for reference…see comment above. Apologize upfront if my code is ‘dizzying’…)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import time

url = 
'https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/browse/Report/USGS%20Numbered%20Series/Open-
File%20Report'
url2 = 'https://pubs.er.usgs.gov'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
pubti_links = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
type(soup)

year_containers = soup.findAll('li',{'class':'pubs-browse-list-theme'})

for year in year_containers[:1]:
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if '/browse/Report/USGS%20Numbered%20Series/Open-
File%20Report/2018' in a['href']:
        link_containers = a.get('href')
        #print (link_containers)
        pubti_links = url2 + link_containers
        #print (pubti_links)
        for pubti_link in pubti_links[:1]:
            response2 = requests.get(pubti_links)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, "html.parser")
            time.sleep(2)
            for elm in  soup2.find_all('li',{'class':'pubs-browse-list-
theme'}):
                for a_elm in elm.findAll('a'):
                    #print(a.get('href'))
                    pub_containers = a_elm.get('href')
                    pubdetails_links = url2 + pub_containers
                    response3 = requests.get(pubdetails_links)
                    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(response3.text, 
"html.parser") 
                    pubdetail_containers = soup3.findAll('dd',{'class':
["" "","dark"]})
                    dd_data = soup3.findAll('dd',{'class':["" 
"","dark"]})
                    #dt_data = soup3.findAll('dt',{'class':["" 
"","dark"]})
                    for dd_item in dd_data:
                        print(dd_item.string)
                    #for dt_item in dt_data:
                        #print (dt_item.string)
```

**Desired result** (the goal is to create a table of all USGS publication for each year):
[Output Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE8yB.png)

Comment: To be clear, for each publication title link, there are "Additional publication details" that I'm looking to extract.